# Recovery mode on android netbook?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, boot

2 years ago I was given a netbook for Christmas and it came with the Android 2.2 OS. Since then I haven't used the netbook much but recently I decided to put Linux Mint on the netbook. But I didn't get that far – as when I turned the device on (and before I could do anything), I was stuck on this screen:

[image: This is what it looks like,]
<sup>(click image for larger variant)</sup>

So I couldn't put Linux mint on it because it is stuck on this screen.

The netbook worked when I first got it. It doesn't have volume keys and I've tried presing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>. I have also tried pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> and nothing happens. I'm at a loss for new ideas on how to fix this so my plan is to try and get into recovery mode so that I can flash another version of android to it.

So my question is how do I get into recovery mode.

I have also tried holding Power On+Home and nothing happens.